# HashMap.merge() через Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream, java-hashmap

Есть метод,  в котором алгоритм прописан через обычную итерацию по List:

```
public static List<UserMealWithExceed> getFilteredWithExceeded(List<UserMeal> mealList, LocalTime startTime, LocalTime endTime, int caloriesPerDay) {
        Map<LocalDate, Integer> caloriesOfDayMap = new HashMap<>();
        List<UserMealWithExceed> userList = new ArrayList<>();
        LocalDate date;
        LocalTime time;

        for (UserMeal um : mealList) {
            date = TimeUtil.toLocalDate(um.getDateTime());
            Integer calories = um.getCalories();
            caloriesOfDayMap.merge(date, calories, Integer::sum);
        }

        for (UserMeal um : mealList) {
            time = TimeUtil.toLocalTime(um.getDateTime());

            if (TimeUtil.isBetween(time, startTime, endTime)) {
                date = TimeUtil.toLocalDate(um.getDateTime());
                int caloriesOfDate = caloriesOfDayMap.get(date);
                boolean isExceeds = caloriesOfDate >= caloriesPerDay;
                userList.add(new UserMealWithExceed(um.getDateTime(), um.getDescription(), um.getCalories(), isExceeds));
            }
        }

        return userList;
    }
```

Задача - реализовать алгоритм через Stream API. Проблема - не могу сообразить, как использовать stream().collect именно для выполнения функции merge(). Прошу помощи

Answer (score 1):

```
public static List<UserMealWithExceed> getFilteredWithExceeded(List<UserMeal> mealList,
        LocalTime startTime, LocalTime endTime, int caloriesPerDay) {

    final Map<LocalDate, Integer> caloriesOfDayMap = 
            mealList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(um->um.getDateTime().toLocalDate(), um->um.getCalories(), Integer::sum));

    return mealList.stream()
            .filter(um -> um.getDateTime().toLocalTime().isAfter(startTime)
                    && um.getDateTime().toLocalTime().isBefore(endTime))
            .map(um->createUserMealWithExceed(caloriesOfDayMap, um, caloriesPerDay))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

}

private static UserMealWithExceed createUserMealWithExceed(Map<LocalDate, Integer> caloriesOfDayMap, UserMeal um, int caloriesPerDay){
    boolean isExceeds = caloriesOfDayMap.get(um.getDateTime().toLocalDate()) >= caloriesPerDay;
    return new UserMealWithExceed(um.getDateTime(), um.getDescription(), um.getCalories(), isExceeds);
}
```

Полагаю, что в классе UserMeal dateTime имеет тип LocalDateTime (иначе это странно). В этом случае никаких дополнительных утилит в виде TimeUtil не требуется, все уже есть из коробки в пакете java.time.

Comment: я через утилиту дергал время и дату по-отдельности из LocalDateTime

Comment: isBefore / isAfter не учитывают граничные значения, т.е. там нет >= или <=, только больше/меньше

Comment: чтобы получит дату и время по отдельности существуют методы toLocalDate() и toLocalTime() соответственно. само слово Before и After дает четкое понимание о том, что делает метод это до и после, никаких "граничных" значений. это вполне ожидаемое поведение. в любом случае вам никто не мешает по прежнему получать значения из утилиты. я вижу только огрызок кода и изложенную проблему - изменить циклы на функционалку. собственно, вот функционалка))

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<UserMealWithExceed> getFilteredWithExceeded(List<UserMeal> mealList, 
                                                               LocalTime startTime, 
                                                               LocalTime endTime, 
                                                               int caloriesPerDay) {

    Map<LocalDate, Integer> caloriesOfDayMap = mealList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(um -> TimeUtil.toLocalDate(um.getDateTime()), 
                    Collectors.summingInt(UserMeal::getCalories)));

    return mealList.stream()
            .filter(um -> TimeUtil.isBetween(TimeUtil.toLocalTime(um.getDateTime()), 
                                             startTime, 
                                             endTime))
            .map(um -> new UserMealWithExceed(um.getDateTime(), 
                                              um.getDescription(), 
                                              um.getCalories(), 
                                              caloriesOfDayMap.get(TimeUtil.toLocalDate(um.getDateTime()) >= caloriesPerDay))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Разумеется, можно насоздавать для каждой операции нужные функциональные объекты и запихнуть громоздкий код в них, будет красивее выглядеть.